# VueJS - Localhost API requests not working on Android Chromium

Tags: vue.js, axios, chromium, httplistener

I am running a vue-project on Chromium 72 on Android v4.4.4 and an API is also running on localhost:8225.

So with the click of a button, I am making a post request using Axios to this localhost API in the project.

```
 var axiosConfig = {
        method: "post",
        url: "http://localhost:8225/info/update",
        data: {},
        timeout: 3000,
        contentType: "application/json",
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(apiUser + ":" + apiPassword),
        },
      };

      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        axios(axiosConfig)
          .then(function (response) {
            var result = response;
            resolve(result);
            console.log("Response", response);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error", error);
            reject(error);
          });
      });
```

But the problem is when I click the button it doesn't hit the API method. It gives `Error: timeout of 3000ms exceeded` and when I removed the timeout and checked the network tab the request remains in a pending state.

I don't think there is a structural error in the code because the same request works from another application running on the device. When the button is clicked the information gets updated.

Also, I tried all the chromium version till v80 same issue exists. So is there any setting that needs to be changed or enabled on Chromium to handle API requests?

**UPDATE:**

The API gets hit but when I checked the value of the User(username and password) on HttpListenerContext object, it shows null. I have cross-checked multiple times and I believe the request structure is correct. I am not sure if Chromium is putting some restrictions while sending the requests or the problem is with the backend like CORS issue or maybe something else.

Comment: Your code want to call localhost:port, you should use a real port number in the url string I guess

Comment: Yes, I am using a real port.

Comment: I believe you are running your app on android and your backend is on your laptop. localhost wont work that way, you need to replace localhost with your IP address

Comment: @AliasgherNooruddin  Another application which is running on android in which this request is working takes the android device's IP as localhost, but I tried with both the IP addresses, my device's as well as my laptop's, didn't work.